# How is Transition Radiation different from EM waves crossing a boundary?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

Just confused my self again :(. Transition radiation is the radiation produced when a charge crosses a boundary between two dielectric materials (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_radiation). As Jackson (chp 13) states, it is the act of the fields having to "reorganize" themselves at the boundary that's creating the radiation.

In a  different light, how is this field reorganization any different from that of an EM wave incident on a boundary of two different dielectric materials (Griffiths chp. 9)?

Thanks for your ideas in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In fact a sharp boundary is not required. It is sufficient that the charge density $$ρ(\bf{x})=∂_{x}⋅E(x)=[∂_{x}ɛ⁻¹(x)]⋅D(x)$$ is not constant. The wikipedia article is somewhat outdated. A fairly recent discussion (of which I was one of the authors) can be found in B. Lastdrager, A. Tip and J. Verhoeven: Phys. Rev. E 61, 2000, p 5767. It presents a detailed discussion of the phenomenon and hopefully answers your question.

Comment: Interesting! Yes, that would make sense due to the fact that the dielectric constant is due in part by the intermolecular forces of the electrons in the material; something I have not thought of at all.

But still does not address my original concern :(

Comment: As to your second question "In a different light, how is this field reorganization any different from that of an EM wave incident on a boundary of two different dielectric materials (Griffiths chp. 9)?", the system is now perturbed by an electron rather than an electromagnetic field. It is now due to Coulomb forces (a longitudinal field) rather than an EM wave (a transverse field) and in general its effect is different.